# ListView scroll to last item WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

how to make scroll rule always at end of the ListView automatic without focus in WPF?

Answer (score 5):

The answers from @pduncan and @MattBurland both have some problems, primarily that they fail to unregister the behaviour properly.

This implementation stores the handler in another attached property so that you can toggle the behaviour on and off, perhaps through a binding.

Note that this applies to `ListView`. If you are using `ListBox`, change occurrences of `ListView` to `ListBox`.

```
public static class ListViewExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollToEndProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScrollToEnd", typeof(bool), typeof(ListViewExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnAutoScrollToEndChanged));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollToEndHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScrollToEndHandler", typeof(NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler), typeof(ListViewExtensions));

    public static bool GetAutoScrollToEnd(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoScrollToEndProperty);
    public static void SetAutoScrollToEnd(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(AutoScrollToEndProperty, value);

    private static void OnAutoScrollToEndChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = s as ListView;

        if (listView == null)
            return;

        var source = (INotifyCollectionChanged)listView.Items.SourceCollection;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler scrollToEndHandler = delegate
            {
                if (listView.Items.Count <= 0)
                    return;
                listView.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
                listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.Items.CurrentItem);
            };

            source.CollectionChanged += scrollToEndHandler;

            listView.SetValue(AutoScrollToEndHandlerProperty, scrollToEndHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            var handler = (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler)listView.GetValue(AutoScrollToEndHandlerProperty);

            source.CollectionChanged -= handler;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<ListView local:ListViewExtensions.AutoScrollToEnd="{Binding Path=AutoScroll}">
```

I also made it a a static class, as you don't need to instantiate it (nor does it need to derive from `DependencyObject`). The cast to `INotifyCollectionChanged` was changed so that errors surface as cast exceptions, not NREs.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this , its working for me :

this.myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[myListView.Items.Count-1]);

if you need more advanced detail you can refere to this [post](http://dutton.me.uk/2013/08/13/auto-scrolling-a-wpf-listview-when-a-new-item-is-added/#comment-67182)

Answer (score 3):

Since @pduncan's answer doesn't include the actual code, here is the code from the link they posted with only a minor modification from me:

```
public class ListBoxExtenders : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollToEndProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScrollToEnd", typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxExtenders), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnAutoScrollToEndChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value of the AutoScrollToEndProperty
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The dependency-object whichs value should be returned</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the given property</returns>
    public static bool GetAutoScrollToEnd(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoScrollToEndProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value of the AutoScrollToEndProperty
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The dependency-object whichs value should be set</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value which should be assigned to the AutoScrollToEndProperty</param>
    public static void SetAutoScrollToEnd(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoScrollToEndProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will be called when the AutoScrollToEnd
    /// property was changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s">The sender (the ListBox)</param>
    /// <param name="e">Some additional information</param>
    public static void OnAutoScrollToEndChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = s as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            var listBoxItems = listBox.Items;
            var data = listBoxItems.SourceCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged;

            var scrollToEndHandler = new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(
                (s1, e1) =>
                {
                    if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        listBoxItems.MoveCurrentToLast();
                        listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItems.CurrentItem);
                    }
                });

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                data.CollectionChanged += scrollToEndHandler;
            else
                data.CollectionChanged -= scrollToEndHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

I modified it to use `MoveCurrentToLast` instead of getting the last item with `listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - 1];`. The reason for this (aside from being a little cleaner anyway) is that there is an edge case where if you have duplicate items in a list, then getting `listBox.Items.Count - 1` and then scrolling to that item might not scroll you to the end of the list (it could even scroll you in the opposite direction!). It would instead scroll you to the *first* instance of that item.

Answer (score 2):

Use an Attached Property.  This article will show you how:
http://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/listbox-automatically-scroll-to-bottom/

Comment: This is the more-correct solution. It's also impressive that something was accomplished in WPF with only 37 lines (plus comments).

Comment: Links go stale, it would be helpful to include the code *in your answer*

Answer (score 0):

For me, these work if each record in the list box is different.  If they are the same it just scrolls to the first one that matches.